# Explode to array and print each element as list item

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I have a set of numbers in a table field in database, the numbers are separated by comma ','.
I am trying to do the following:

Step 1. : SELECT set of numbers from database and explode it to array :

```
$array =  explode(',', $set_of_numbers);
```

Step 2. : Print each element of the array as list item by using `foreach loop` :

```
foreach ($array as $list_item => $set_of_numbers){
    echo "<li>";
    print_r(array_list_items($set_of_numbers));
    echo "</li>";}
```

Please anybody tell me what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: What does your function array_list_items() return?

Comment: You can learn it more here - http://thecodetutorial.com/what-is-explode/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$numbers = '1,2,3';

$array =  explode(',', $numbers);

foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo "<li>$item</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your original `$set_of_numbers` is simply a CSV string, something like `1,2,3,4,...`, then your foreach is "mostly" ok. But your variable naming is quite bonkers, and your print-r() call uncesary:

```
$array = explode(',', $set_of_numbers);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   echo "<li>$key: $value</li>";
}
```

Assuming that 1,2,3,4... string, you'd get

```
<li>0: 1</li>
<li>1: 2</li>
<li>2: 3</li>
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = "1,2,3";

$array =  explode(",", $numbers);

/* count length of array */
$arrlength = count($array);

/* using for while */
$x = 0; 

while ($x < $arrlength) {

  echo "<li>$array[$x]</li>" . PHP_EOL;
  $x++;

}
echo PHP_EOL;

/* using for classic */
for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

  echo "<li>$array[$x]</li>" .  PHP_EOL;

}
echo PHP_EOL;    

/* using for each assoc */
foreach ($array as $value) {

  echo "<li>$value</li>" .  PHP_EOL;

}
echo PHP_EOL;    

/* using for each assoc key */
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

  echo "<li>$key => $value</li>" .  PHP_EOL;

}
```

```css
body, html, iframe { 
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  overflow: hidden ;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://ideone.com/ZqT4Yi" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to explode on the commas.  You can just replace each comma with an ending tag followed by an opening tag and then wrap your whole string in an opening and closing tag.

```
$set_of_numbers = '1,2,3';
echo '<li>' . str_replace(',', '</li><li>', $set_of_numbers) . '</li>';
// outputs: <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
```

No looping is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer for your question to get ride of your problem

```
$Num = '1,2,3,4,5,';
$Array = explode(',',$Num);
foreach ($Array as $Items)
{
echo "<li>&Items</li>"; // This line put put put in the list.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved by the following code snippet:

```
<?php
$my_numbers = '1,12,3.2,853.3,4545,221';
echo '<ul>';
foreach(explode(',', $my_numbers) AS $my_number){
    echo '<li>'.$my_number.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The above code will output the following HTML:

```
<ul><li>1</li><li>12</li><li>3.2</li><li>853.3</li><li>4545</li><li>221</li></ul>
```

Credits: http://dwellupper.io/post/49/understanding-php-explode-function-with-examples