# How to do fuzzy logic for search function in PHP and SQL Server?

Tags: php, search, logic, fuzzy

I am working on a webpage linked to my database that has a search feature as the main function. Users have to search for Company's name to check which group the company belongs to etc. However, I need a fuzzy search logic to do company name screening. I tried many methods but the challenge is the company names are long. I used `WHERE NAME LIKE %keywordfromform%` but its not fuzzy enough.

For example:

Actual: ABC Company 123 ROAD
User search: Road 123 ABC Company

The result should appear but it doesn't show, this leads to inaccuracy in searches.

Comment: Use full text searching, or explode on every space and do a separate `like` comparison for each term.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, hmm.. which one would you recommend? I am new to this and its quite urgent,  would prefer the easier solution.. @user3783243

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @AngelLim Full text will probably be faster, and more accurate. I haven't used the mssql full text in a while though so I can't advise much more on it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/get-started-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @user3783243 I tried the fulltext and it took really long to execute query (not sure what the reason is, could it be because i am using intranet?) the first time i tried, the result wasnt very accurate. and the subsequent time i could not execute because it took really long. Do you know why?

Comment: Might be worth looking at https://serverfault.com/questions/182665/does-mssql-server-have-the-equivalent-of-mysqls-query-logs to see why it is slow. Try the query just on the DB first, if it takes long there you know it is a full text index issue. If it works fine there then it might be a network issue between DB server and your php.

Comment: I have only tried on the db, and it is already very slow TT. Haven't tried on my php yet tho. @user3783243

Comment: You should add the new query to the question and the results from profiling. Also I'd tag mssql, and remove the PHP tag since you are just trying to get it to run well in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

actual : "ABC Company 123 ROAD" 
user = "Road 123 ABC Company"
use `explode` or `preg_split` for splitting the string into an array. As you don't know the order so it would be better to break the query string and search by word instead of searching for a whole string.

If you need `any` of the words

```
   SELECT * FROM table
   WHERE column LIKE '%word1%'
   OR column1 LIKE '%word2%'
   OR column1 LIKE '%word3%'
```

If you need `all` of the words to be present

```
   SELECT * FROM table
   WHERE column LIKE '%word1%'
   AND column1 LIKE '%word2%'
   AND column1 LIKE '%word3%'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How do I use the explode or preg_split?

Comment: explode(separator,string) [check this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257063/explode-to-array-and-print-each-element-as-list-item/16257088)